# Access sqlite database from 2 python files

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been trying to create a sqlite database using one python file and access data from it using another, but keep getting an error. I have 2 files, main.py and file2.py

`main.py`:

```
import sqlite3, os
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
queryCurs = conn.cursor()

def createTable():
    queryCurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)''')

def addInitial(name):
    queryCurs.execute('''INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES (?)''',(name,))

createTable()
    addInitial("John")

conn.commit()

os.system('file2.py')
```

and here is the code in `file2.py`

```
    import sqlite3, os, time
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    queryCurs = conn.cursor()

    queryCurs.execute('SELECT name FROM test WHERE id=1')
    for i in queryCurs:
        for j in i:
            name = j
            print name

    conn.commit()
```

I receive the error: OperationalError: no such table: test

Comment: In-memory databases are not shared by definition.

Comment: Thanks, what about databases that are not in memory, can those be shared? e.g. conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

Comment: Yes, those can be shared by multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

Each `connect` call creates its own in-memory database.

To share the same in-memory database, create a single connection and share that Python object in both modules.

Comment: Thanks. Would it work if I created a db that is not in memory e.g. conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db') and then did the same in the second file? Or is that still wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to have two different files with the same file name?